# Something in Ghost not understand, exports.init = function init() {} is automatically called when required

Tags: node.js

in `Ghost` module `models`'s index.js:

```
/**
 * Dependencies
 */

var _ = require('lodash'),

    exports,
    models;

/**
 * Expose all models
 */

exports = module.exports;

models = [
    'accesstoken',
    'app-field',
    'app-setting',
    'app',
    'client-trusted-domain',
    'client',
    'permission',
    'post',
    'refreshtoken',
    'role',
    'settings',
    'subscriber',
    'tag',
    'user'
];

function init() {
    exports.Base = require('./base');

    models.forEach(function (name) {
        _.extend(exports, require('./' + name));
    });
}

/**
 * Expose `init`
 */

exports.init = init;
```

When this code is required, but the `init` method is not called. All stuff it exported in `init` method can be used.

Here's how it used:

```
dataProvider    = require('../models')
```

then

```
dataProvider.Post.findPage(options)
```

The exported `init` method is not called, **WHY???**

Comment: @slugonamission check this out: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/api/posts.js

Answer (score 1):

`core/server/models/index.js` exports one function `init` as expected.
On server start `core/server/index.js` define `models = require('./models')` and call `models.init();` on line 68. So, there is no magic with `init` :(

P.S. Ghost is [*here*](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost)

Comment: I find it in one of the "then" functions according to your answer. thanks